# Patch small holes in an internal stucco wall

Tags: stucco, hole-repair, drywall-mud

In a room that was added on to the house (many years ago), two of the internal walls (that used to be external walls) are stucco.  There are a couple of approx. 1 inch diameter holes in the stucco that I want to patch, and several smaller screw and anchor holes.

The other walls in the room also have some holes and I already purchased the mud (powder) to patch these with.  (The other walls are ordinary painted drywall.)

Given that the stucco walls aren't exposed to the elements, how important is it to patch them with a compound designed for stucco patching versus just using ordinary mud?  (Mud = drywall joint compound.)

I am interested to know:

1. The correct, professional way to patch the stucco;
2. Any drawbacks (especially in appearance or longevity) associated with doing it a different way;
3. Whether it's really possible to get the texture to match if I do use a compound designed for stucco patching.

(I'm patching the walls in preparation for repainting the whole room.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching the texture of an existing surface (any textured surface, not specifically stucco) is an art form that takes years of trial & error experience and rarely if ever looks *exactly* the same.

The composition/material used is not an issue considering the (small) size of the repairs you describe. Stucco can be textured infinite ways (sand finish, spanish lace, rough, etc.) and you did not describe or attach a pic depicting yours. Your best bet is to experiment (on a sacrificial surface) with different materials/products: mortar applied with different techniques, stucco patch, acoustic ceiling patch, drywall mud, plaster with sand added, etc. The options are limitless, start trying.